# Insert existing Buttons into Context Toolstrip - Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip

I have a GUI and some buttons in WinForms. Now I want to create a Toolstrip Menu and move the buttons into the menu. Is it possible without copying the whole code into the new Toolstrip entries? I just want to link the buttons somehow.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. It is not possible to move the existing buttons into the `ToolStrip` but you can create new ones and rewire them:

- first: look for the name of the current event handler by selecting the old button, press F4 and switch to the action menu (the lightning bolt in the properties window):

[image: Step-1]

- second: select the new button and pick the same event handler as for the old button:

[image: Step-2]

- finally you can remove the old button.

Comment: I've been downvoted - that's interesting :-) how so? Who was it may show up.

Comment: downvoted? sorry for that! I think I hit the wrong button! Can't vote up anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

Buttons click events code can be linked directly to toolstrip buttons. 
All availables events can be showed in Action->Click in design time.

**EDIT:**

I assume that you have a form in your project with some buttons, eg.: button1, button2.

For each Button you wrote a click action, in your code something like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // YOUR CODE FOR BUTTON1
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // YOUR CODE FOR BUTTON2
}
```

Then you can use those methods/action for toolbar's buttons.

The easiest way to do is to add buttons to tollbar and use Events (with property panel, the little bolt icon) to choose the correct method to assign to each tolbar's button Click event/action.

Comment: I don't understand. How can I do this? What is "Action" ?